# Full screen background image in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How to give our setup a background full screen image in Inno Setup compiler.

Like this picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Do not do that. It's against Windows design guidelines.

---

Anyway, if you have to, enable legacy full screen installer mode using the [`WindowVisible=yes` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_windowvisible) and then modify the (now visible) background window via `MainForm` global variable of type [`TMainForm`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TMainForm).

```pascal
[Setup]
WindowVisible=yes

[Files]
Source: "back.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  BackgroundImage: TBitmapImage;
begin
  BackgroundImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
  BackgroundImage.Parent := MainForm;
  BackgroundImage.SetBounds(0, 0, MainForm.ClientWidth, MainForm.ClientHeight);
  BackgroundImage.Stretch := True;
  ExtractTemporaryFile('back.bmp');
  BackgroundImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\back.bmp'));
end;
```

[image]

Comment: I found it useful and upvoted meanwhile I was waiting for an answer here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502926/inno-setup-display-a-message-in-separate-window-visibible-throughout-an-instal/52510464#52510464