# Display a message in separate window visible throughout an installation

Tags: inno-setup

I already used `InfoBeforeFile` directive, with an "Important notice" text file.

But I would prefer the user could continue to read the instructions throughout an installation (e.g. in a separate window).

Any clue?

---

Added the final result, thanks again to Martin Prikryl

[image: added the final result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`CreateCustomForm` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcustomform) to create a separate window for your message.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "important.txt"; Flags: dontcopy;

[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  InfoForm: TSetupForm;
  InfoMemo: TRichEditViewer;
begin
  InfoForm := CreateCustomForm;
  Log(IntToStr(WizardForm.Left));
  Log(IntToStr(WizardForm.Width));
  InfoForm.Left := WizardForm.Left + WizardForm.Width; 

  InfoForm.Width := ScaleX(400); 
  InfoForm.Caption := 'Important message';
  InfoForm.Top := WizardForm.Top;
  InfoForm.Height := WizardForm.Height;
  InfoForm.Position := poDesigned;
  InfoForm.Show();

  InfoMemo := TRichEditViewer.Create(InfoForm);
  InfoMemo.Parent := InfoForm;
  InfoMemo.Left := ScaleX(40);
  InfoMemo.Top := ScaleX(40);
  InfoMemo.Width := InfoForm.ClientWidth - 2 * ScaleX(40);
  InfoMemo.Height := InfoForm.ClientHeight - 2 * ScaleX(40);
  InfoMemo.ScrollBars := ssVertical;
  InfoMemo.ReadOnly := ssVertical;
  InfoMemo.WantReturns := ssVertical;
  InfoMemo.WantReturns := False;

  ExtractTemporaryFile('important.txt');
  InfoMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\important.txt'));
end;
```

[image]

---

*Though, wouldn't it be better to display the message on the side of the installer wizard?*

Comment: This is PERFECT ! thanks twice (also for the very clear reeditioning) BTW I already found useful your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683399/full-screen-background-image-in-inno-setup?noredirect=1&lq=1